# How can I add study name to points in L'abbé plot in R-metafor?

Tags: r, plot, metafor

Is it possible to add the name of the study to the "point" that represents the study in the L'abbé plot? I am using the metafor package.

```
 # Load package
 library(metafor)

 # Load data
 data(dat.bcg)

 # Code 
 ex <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, 
      di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="OR",
      slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "), method="FE")

# L'abbé plot
labbe(ex, transf = exp, ylab="Test group", xlab="Control")
```

The study name can be found in

```
dat.bcg$author
```

Thank you,
C.

Comment: Do you want to add all the names or just some? All would b ea bit trickier because of the way they overlap.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. The data I posted here is just an example - my data is different with more space between the points. Would it be possible for you to produce an example where some of the points have text and where all points have text?

Comment: I'll give it a go today, sorry for not putting up some kind of answer yesterday. It seems like it should be doable but the question is where are the points for those dots stored. I'll see if I can extract that. After that the text placement will be a matter of preference.

Comment: I can't get a good way of doing this using the metafor package. Part of it is that I can't see where points for the plot are coming from. I presumed they were the proportion of the treatment and control group which experienced the event, but when you plot those points on top of the plot they don't overlap with the points the plot generates. Other than that, to put labels onto the plot that don't overlap would be a lot easier using directplot in ggplot (in fact I don't know of a simple way to do this other than that).

Comment: Since `measure="OR"` and `transf=exp`, the points correspond to the odds of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the package so that `labbe()` now returns (invisibly) the coordinates of the points that were drawn (and their sizes). You can install the `devel` version of the package as described here:

https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor/blob/master/README.md#installation

To use the same example:

```
pos <- labbe(ex, transf = exp, ylab="Test group", xlab="Control")
text(pos$x, pos$y, dat.bcg$author, pos=4)
```

The text overlaps heavily in this example, but maybe this works better for your data.